# how to get Model "values" without a foreach over it?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model

I am learning MVC and for do this I am developing a "smart forum".
How can I get value from Model directly , without foreach iteration when data is "a single row"?

```
@model IEnumerable<WebApplication28.ModelsFromDb.ArgomentiViewModel>
@foreach (var item in Model)
    {

        <dl class="dl-horizontal">
            <dt>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.NomeArea)
            </dt>

            <dd>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NomeArea) 
            </dd>
}
```

Comment: If your data is a single row, then you shouldn't pass in an `IEnumerable` into the view.

Answer (score 1):

That would be messy code if you keep your model type as `IEnumerable<>`. So I suggest you change that, in one of two ways.

If you know there will always be a single item, why do you need to have a enumerable at all? Just remove it and make sure to return the underlying object from the controller:

```
@model WebApplication28.ModelsFromDb.ArgomentiViewModel
```

If you have to deal with collections, I bet it is a more specific type you are returning from the controller. If it is a list, you could use `IList<>`, which has many more operations, and which you could index:

```
@model IList<WebApplication28.ModelsFromDb.ArgomentiViewModel>
...
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model[0].NomeArea)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your ActionMethod is going to have to only return a single row, not an IEnumerable.  Use the SingleOrDefault() method on your entity.  Return that in your view to ensure that you're only going to at most, return one row.

```
@model WebApplication28.ModelsFromDb.ArgomentiViewModel
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
       <dt>
          @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.NomeArea)
        </dt>
        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NomeArea) 
        </dd>
    </dl>
```